# How can I use CMake to link C++ packages to SWIG wrappers?

Tags: cmake, swig

I am trying to build a simple program that uses C++ packages in Golang. I decided to use CMake and SWIG to handle the linking and Golang module generation. The program works fine when I am using C++ standard libraries, but I was wondering how can I extend to even work with external C++ packages?

I tried to use CMake's `target_link_library` but that did not work. I also tried building my own library and link the external libraries to it and then link my library to the SWIG Module in CMake, but that also did not work.

In this example assume that foo is an external C++ package installed using VCPKG.

here is my code:
CMakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.21)
project ("test")

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_library(test_lib "main.cpp" "lib_header.h")
add_executable(test "test.cpp")
find_package(SWIG)

include (UseSWIG)
set (SWIG_FILE "go.i")
set_source_files_properties(${SWIG_FILE} PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set(USE_SWIG_DEPENDENCIES TRUE)

set(SWIG_MODULE_NAME "foo")
set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS -c++ -go -cgo -intgosize 64)

swig_add_library(${SWIG_MODULE_NAME} TYPE STATIC LANGUAGE go OUTPUT_DIR go_module SOURCES ${SWIG_FILE})

   
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 17
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
        CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)

find_package(foo REQUIRED )
target_link_libraries(${SWIG_MODULE_NAME} PRIVATE foo::foo)
target_link_libraries(test_lib PRIVATE foo::foo)
target_link_libraries(${SWIG_MODULE_NAME} PRIVATE test_lib)
```

lib_header.h

```
#ifndef test__
#define test__
int run();
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "lib_header.h"
#include <foo.h>

int run(){
   
    foo::do_something();
    return 0;
}
```

go.i

```
%module go_cpp
%{
#include "/absolute/path/to/lib_header.h"
#include "/absolute/path/to/main.cpp"
%}

%include "lib_header.h"
```

and here is the error I get when I try to use the Golang module:

```
/absolute/path/to/main.cpp:7:10: fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory 7 | #include <foo.h>
```

I am using CMake 3.27.3 and Golang 1.20 on Linux Ubuntu 20.04. Any Idea how to accomplish my goal?